# Springboot web application: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot

I have a springboot application which includes Post and get Rest API. I have included index.html in path src/main/resources/templates/index.html. Inside index.html i m calling the javascript. But the browser errors out saying Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status controller.js of 404 ().

Due to this its not able to find the js file and perform required operation when i click on the button. Please let me know what changes has to be made.

code snippet:

I have js file inside static/js folder. I tried changing the file path location but not helping.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/controller.js" th:src="@{/js/controller.js}"></script> I am calling the script with this inside index.html

Comment: In the logs it says, did not find handler method. RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/js/controller.js]
19:34:28.706 [http-nio-8989-exec-2] WARN  org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/js/controller.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
19:34:28.706 [http-nio-8989-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet -